# How to browse webpages through proxy server

Tags: proxy

I made a proxy server,and I'm testing it using a client name Proxifier.

I made the first part with autentication to work,but i don't know what to do next.

I called Connect() an the address received from the client,but that is from a webpage.
So i need to connect to the webpage? What next then? I can't browse the net with the proxy on.

So i hope someone could help me an what to do next.Thanks.

Comment: your question is incomplete or vague. which programming language did you program in? can you post the code giving you problem

Answer (score 0):

to test a proxy server is simple as these.

In your browser, configure the proxy settings to the ip:port of your proxy server, in these case  if you are testing on local machine, your ip is 127.0.0.1 and you are listening on port 80.

browse a webpage mostly google with the browser and see if it loads properly, if it does, then you proxy server is working